# Glob in C++ and print the results

Tags: c++, glob, stdio

I'm just trying to glob everything in a directory and print the list of results, but I get an empty printf:

```
#include <glob.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int result;
  glob_t buffer;
  buffer.gl_offs = 10;
  glob("*", GLOB_DOOFFS, NULL, &buffer);
  printf((char*)buffer.gl_pathv);
}
```

What does work is

```
printf("%i", buffer.gl_pathc));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need to reserve empty slots in glob? Do not include `GLOB_DOOFFS` if you don't need it.
And don't forget to free memory for glob.

Try something like this:

```
#include <glob.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    glob_t globbuf;
    int err = glob("*", 0, NULL, &globbuf);
    if(err == 0)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < globbuf.gl_pathc; i++)
        {
            printf("%s\n", globbuf.gl_pathv[i]);
        }

        globfree(&globbuf);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, I didn't need the reserved slots and thanks for the globfree function.